# ASP.NET VB.NET show animated gif on page while file copy in Progress

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a webpage and a button that copies a file to the server.
I would like to show on the screen the animated file copy gif while this is happening. And hide it afterwards like this:

```
me.image.visible = true
copy file routine.....
me.image.visible = false
```

The button copies the file fine but the gif is not shown as its enabled and disabled within the code without a postback to refresh the screen.

If this isn't the correct approach, which way should I go?

Comment: You'll have to show the image with javascript, not with the code behind. This should be done on button click.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with that animated .gif stuff it will just drive you crazy. Use pure code. Spin.js

It is the best solution for this I promise.

[Spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are really dead set on the gif (and not just changing the cursor from default to waiting) then you can make a form with a transparent background and a border free picture box. Make the picture box's image the gif as the source.

But I'd just do the mouse as a wait cursor instead.